# Counter mysteriously increments in loop

Tags: javascript

I have a simple loop which passes some data from a list through other functions, but when those functions return, the counter has mysteriously incremented:

```
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            alert(i) // ONE
            doWhatever(list[i]);
            alert(i) // TWO
        }
```

`doWhatever()` looks like this:

```
function doWhatever (obj) {
      for (i in obj) createThing(obj[i]);
}
```

How is it possible for the value of `i` in the original loop to change this way?

Comment: I suspect you changed your code too much for the question. Can you write a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ? What is inside the `sorted` array ?

Comment: @dystroy I honestly have not changed it at all -- that's a literal cut n' paste -- but I just narrowed the problem down further (`i` has incremented) -- which changes the nature of the question (so, slightly re-written).  I'll try for a SSCCE...

Comment: From your example you are using `i` as a global variable, make it local using `var` (e.g., `for (var i = 0; ...)`).

Comment: did you try it with console.log instead ? of course your alerts are kind of standing above the loop

Comment: For posterity, I've edited this down to make the question/problem more canonical/generalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to forget the `var` keyword.

Look at your code. And every where you have

```
for (i = 0; ...
```

change it to

```
for (var i = 0; ...
```

Because all the loops written without the var keyword change the same `i` variable (well, more precisely a loop written as such change the `i` of the enclosing scope having defined it, which is often the global one, especially if you never properly defined `i`).

Comment: BTW: If forgetting `var` changed the result of your `i` mid-loop, then there are other places in your code where you aren't using `var i`.

Comment: @cpburnz That's not necessarily true... if adding `var` changed your code that just means you were using the variable `i` somewhere else in you code, probably in a similar `for loop`, with or without a `var` keyword. Using `var` here just means you are redefining the variable at that context. In a previous loop you could've used `var i`, and in the this loop `i` would still be referencing it.

What you are thinking of is `let i`, which is coming soon. That would limit the scope of `i` to this loop, then kill it after it exits.

Comment: @Joseph Re-using the local `i` wouldn't change its value mid-loop though. I meant `i` was probably used unintentionally as a global in other functions since it was being altered randomly mid-loop. Most likely the other `i`s were in similar for-loops as well which I've done many times accidentally.

Comment: It depends where all this code lives. JavaScript checks for a variable definition in the local environment (as in the `doWhatever` function) and if not found, looks in the next encapsulating environment. Since neither of these are defined, assuming `i` is never defined, JavaScript automatically defines it in the global environment. Which means `doWhatever` would edit the same `i` variable in the for loop. Had another loop used `var i`, then JavaScript would've simply stopped looking when it found that definition, and would still reference the same variable. The difference is the scoping of `i`